# How to add panel inside foreach loop

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I am just learning c# windows form application. For a several days, i am trying to add some data that came from List to panel using foreach loop but got some error there. It show me only first data. Please guys tell me what am i going wrong. I want show all the data came from list and bind it into panel so that panel got looped according to data.

```
private void loopPanel(List<Bug> list)
{
    foreach (var bug in list)
    {
        int x = 56;
        Panel panel = new Panel();
        this.panelBugs.Controls.Add(panel);

        Label lblProject = new Label();
            Label lblClass = new Label();
            Label lblMethod = new Label();
            PictureBox pictureBox = new PictureBox();

        //
        //panel
        //
        panel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkOliveGreen;
        panel.Controls.Add(lblMethod);
        panel.Controls.Add(lblClass);
        panel.Controls.Add(lblProject);
        panel.Controls.Add(pictureBox);
        panel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, ++x+66);
        panel.Name = panel + bug.BugId.ToString();
        panel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(535, 100);
        panel.TabIndex = 1;
        //panel.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(panel_Paint);
        panel.SuspendLayout();

        //
        //lblProject
        //
        lblProject.AutoSize = true;
        lblProject.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        lblProject.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
        lblProject.Name = lblProject + bug.BugId.ToString();
        lblProject.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 16);
        lblProject.TabIndex = 1;
        lblProject.Text = "Project: "+ bug.ProjectName;

        //
        //lblClass
        //
        lblClass.AutoSize = true;
        lblClass.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        lblClass.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 34);
        lblClass.Name = lblClass + bug.BugId.ToString();
        lblClass.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(42, 16);
        lblClass.TabIndex = 2;
        lblClass.Text = "Class: " + bug.ClassName;

        //
        //lblMethod
        //
        lblMethod.AutoSize = true;
        lblMethod.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        lblMethod.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 71);
        lblMethod.Name = lblMethod + bug.BugId.ToString();
        lblMethod.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(53, 16);
        lblMethod.TabIndex = 3;
        lblMethod.Text = "Method: " + bug.MethodName;

        //
        //pictureBox
        //
        pictureBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(391, 3);
        pictureBox.Name = pictureBox + bug.BugId.ToString();
        pictureBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(141, 94);
        pictureBox.TabIndex = 0;
        pictureBox.TabStop = false;
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(pictureBox)).BeginInit();

        panel.ResumeLayout(false);
        panel.PerformLayout();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(pictureBox)).EndInit();
    }
}
```

```
try
{
    BugDAO bugDao = new BugDAO();
    List<Bug> list = bugDao.getAllBugs();
    loopPanel(list);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Thanks! hoping for positive result.

Comment: Post your errors into your question, otherwise we don't know what's going wrong.

Comment: dont show me any error it show only one panel but what i need is panel should be shown according to data that came from list. Currently i have six items

Comment: You need to change x each loop. Change x+66 to x+=66 maybe.

Comment: @JohnWu not working

Comment: You are using the same labels/picturebox each iteration of the loop. It looks like you just opened up the `.Designer` file and copied out the init code for each one. You can't do that, it will remove it from the other ones when you re-initialize it.

Comment: @RonBeyer the how can i do it. can you give me some suggestin

Comment: Move the declaration inside the loop for starters, that way you are creating new controls instead of reusing the old ones.

Comment: @RonBeyer not working yet.

Comment: "Not working" is not at all helpful in helping to determine the problem. What is it doing and what is the expected behavior? Have you stepped through it with your debugger?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171181/discussion-between-nishan-and-ron-beyer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is solved after replacing `x` outside of loop.

```
private void loopPanel(List<Bug> list)
    {
         int x = 56;
         foreach (var bug in list)
         {//56
            //int x = 0;
            Panel panel = new Panel();
            this.panelBugs.Controls.Add(panel);

            Label lblProject = new Label();
            Label lblClass = new Label();
            Label lblMethod = new Label();
            PictureBox pictureBox = new PictureBox();
            //
            //panel
            //
            panel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkOliveGreen;
            panel.Controls.Add(lblMethod);
            panel.Controls.Add(lblClass);
            panel.Controls.Add(lblProject);
            panel.Controls.Add(pictureBox);
            panel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, x);
            x += 105;
            panel.Name = panel + bug.BugId.ToString();
            panel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(535, 100);
            panel.TabIndex = 1;
            //panel.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(panel_Paint);
            panel.SuspendLayout();
            //
            //lblProject
            //
            lblProject.AutoSize = true;
            lblProject.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            lblProject.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
            lblProject.Name = lblProject + bug.BugId.ToString();
            lblProject.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 16);
            lblProject.TabIndex = 1;
            lblProject.Text = "Project: "+ bug.ProjectName;

            //
            //lblClass
            //
            lblClass.AutoSize = true;
            lblClass.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            lblClass.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 34);
            lblClass.Name = lblClass + bug.BugId.ToString();
            lblClass.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(42, 16);
            lblClass.TabIndex = 2;
            lblClass.Text = "Class: " + bug.ClassName;

            //
            //lblMethod
            //
            lblMethod.AutoSize = true;
            lblMethod.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            lblMethod.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 71);
            lblMethod.Name = lblMethod + bug.BugId.ToString();
            lblMethod.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(53, 16);
            lblMethod.TabIndex = 3;
            lblMethod.Text = "Method: " + bug.MethodName;

            //
            //pictureBox
            //
            pictureBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(391, 3);
            pictureBox.Name = pictureBox + bug.BugId.ToString();
            pictureBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(141, 94);
            pictureBox.TabIndex = 0;
            pictureBox.TabStop = false;
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(pictureBox)).BeginInit();

            panel.ResumeLayout(false);
            panel.PerformLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(pictureBox)).EndInit();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You take the location of the panel in order of each other.

`int lastTop=0;
foreach(....){ var p=new panel();p.Top=lastTop;lastTop=p.Height;}`